# iPhone InApp Purchase Automatic renewal is not working

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Could it be that Auto-renewal subscription is not supported in all the countries?

When I create a test user from **Israel**, I receive a message in the application that
**"Subscriptions not supported. Automatically renewing subscriptions are not supported in your storefront at this time"**

But when I run the same application code and use another test user defined in another country it works fine.

Is there a list of countries for which auto-renewal subscription is supported or
in opposite the countries were it is not supported.

Answer (score 5):

Here is (possibly) the real reason:

> As of January 1st 2009, Israeli law does not permit automatic renewal
>   of subscriptions without explicit notification and consent of the
>   subscriber.

[Here](http://www.consumers.org.il/category/contract-renewals) is a link (Hebrew) to an article explaining the law.
I strongly believe Apple took the easy part of just blocking the service instead of enabling notifications.
I totally agree that this is outrageous, since, as an Israeli citizen I cannot subscribe to quite a few electronic publications. 
I am not familiar with the proper APIs, but I'm sure there is a way to allow manual renewal and I am also sure Apple will block that as well.

Regards,
Misha

Comment: None that I'm aware of except using an American credit card with an American AppleID... :-(
Some of the publications I know of, came up with an alternate method of subscription thereby bypassing this restriction (The New Yorker for example). But it is up to the publication to provide a solution, until this policy (of blocking Israel) is changed by Apple.

Answer (score 4):

In [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4098), at the bottom, it says: "Auto-renewing subscriptions are not available in Israel"

gotta love apple.